# Ruby on Rails - routing error when using nested resources with form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, embedded-resource

So I have a relationship where **service** has_many **statuses**

I have this in my routes.rb file

```
resources :services do
  resources :statuses
end
```

and this is my statuses_controller file

```
class StatusesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @status = Status.new(:parent_id => params[:parent_id])
  end  

  def create
    @service = current_user.services.find(params[:id])
    @status = Status.new(params[:status])
    if @status.save
      flash[:notice] = "New status created."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Error creating new status."
    end
    redirect_to service_statuses_path
  end
end
```

and I'm getting an error:

```
undefined method `statuses_path' for #<#<Class:0x000001045dbb28>:0x00000104554e48>
```

when trying to load:

```
http://localhost:3000/services/2/statuses/new
```

with the file views/statuses/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [@service, @status], :path =>service_statuses_path do |f|%>
  <%= f.label :status %>
  <%= f.text_field :state %><br />

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Why is it giving me an undefined method `statuses_path' still?

Comment: can you run 'rake routes' at the command prompt and paste what shows up there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is the cause of error. But you have to change the method call

```
service_statuses_path
```

to

```
service_statuses_path(@service, @status)
```

which will generate the path like below.

/services/service_id/statuses/status_id

Comment: now getting this:  No route matches {:controller=>"statuses", :service_id=>nil, :format=>#<Status id: nil, time: nil, state: nil, message: nil, service_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}

Comment: you don't need :path option here.Just use <%= form_for [@service, @status] do |f|%>